# Getting the values of the select option with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a small form that is supposed to update shift time values in a database. The form inputs are processed with javascript before being sent to a php function that processes the request with the database.

The code for the form and the submit is:

```
<p><strong>Edit this shift:</strong></p>
<form class="col s12" action"includes/process_update.php" name="shift-update-form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s3">
        <select name="day" id="day">
            <option value=" disabled selected>Select Day</option>
            <option value="0">Sunday</option>
            <option value="1">Monday</option>
            <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="4">Thursday</option>
            <option value="5">Friday</option>
            <!-- <option value="6">Saturday</option> -->
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
        <input placeholder="3:00PM" id="start_time" type="text" class="validate">
        <label class="active" for="start_time">Start Time</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
        <input placeholder="6:00PM" id="end_time" type="text" class="validate">
        <label class="active" for="end_time">End Time</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
        <a onclick="return shift_update_form(this.form, this.form.day.value, this.form.start_time, this.form.end_time);" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But, when I click the button to submit, I am given the error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'day' of undefined"`

So, how do I get the value of the dropdown and pass it as a variable to a javascript function for processing?

Comment: can you also post your js?

Comment: why are you passing all those "this" to `shift_update_form()`? you are doing Javascript wrong.

Comment: Your first option (`Select Day`) is missing the closing double-quote in the `value`. Though the problem is likely in your `shift_update_form` function, which you'll need to post for further help.

Comment: I don't think `<a>` elements have a `form` property. That's only available in input field elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `this` in the `onclick` event of a link, so in that context, `this` refers to the link itself, which doesn't have a property of `form`. The `form` property is only available for the form elements like `input`.

You can convert your link to a submit button and it will work:

```js
function shift_update_form(a, b, c, d) {
  console.log(a.name);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
  console.log(d);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Edit this shift:</strong></p>
<form class="col s12" action "includes/process_update.php" name="shift-update-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <select name="day" id="day">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Day</option>
            <option value="0">Sunday</option>
            <option value="1">Monday</option>
            <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="4">Thursday</option>
            <option value="5">Friday</option>
            <!-- <option value="6">Saturday</option> -->
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <input placeholder="3:00PM" id="start_time" type="text" class="validate">
      <label class="active" for="start_time">Start Time</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <input placeholder="6:00PM" id="end_time" type="text" class="validate">
      <label class="active" for="end_time">End Time</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <button type="submit" onclick="return shift_update_form(this.form, this.form.day.value, this.form.start_time.value, this.form.end_time.value);" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note: I changed your passed parameters from

```
this.form.start_time, this.form.end_time
```

to

```
this.form.start_time.value, this.form.end_time.value
```

because I think you wanted the values of those fields just like you did with the `day` field.

I also closed the form (the closing tag is missing in your code), and I closed the double-quotes of the value of the first option in the `select` element. The `shift_update_form()` function that I provided is just for demo, but the code above should work with your `shift_update_form()` function. If you have troubles with it, then post add it to your question so we can help you.

Comment: I will give this a try, and then come back with the vote!

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I didn't realize that `this` referred to the link and not the form. Thats exactly what I needed!

Comment: Yes, that's how works, but this is probably not the best design. You can pass only one parameter to the function `onclick="return shift_update_form(this);"` or `onclick="return shift_update_form(this.form);"` and then in the function you can get the four values from the passed parameter. However, I personally would pass nothing to the function and get everything there by ID.

Answer (score 0):

`this.form` won't work in `<a>` elements. If you're using jQuery, you can select the elements by their IDs using its selector function.

```
<a onclick="return shift_update_form($('#day').val(), $('#start_time').val(), $('#end_time').val());" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
```